# Is there any documentation on how many times an iOS Smart App Banner Surfaces? Does it render with every single webpage open?

Tags: ios, iphone, smartbanner

my site has a Smart app banner deployed, but i am not certain if it shows up every single time a visitor goes to the page.  does it always render?  if not, how often?  what are the particulars here?

Comment: Reading the docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) seems to indicate that it always appears (if the app is supported on the user’s device and location).

Comment: interesting.  we were testing...and then it stopped showing up.  i thought there was a way to dismiss the banner for a set number of days.